# Python3: os.path.isdir(path) is True for a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a computer with Windows10 and Ubuntu virtual machine.

There is a file with the name `log` in a shared folder that contains precisely one Unix EOL character. It was created by the virtual machine.

In the virtual machine, the following happens:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isdir('/media/path/to/log')
True
```

Hence, python mistakenly thinks that `log` is a directory (for example, the call `list(os.listdir('/media/path/to/log'))` raises the `NotADirectoryError`).

The same happens when I insert the relative path.

If I call `isdir` in Windows command line, it always returns False as expected.

Comment: What command created the file?

Comment: (I wonder if the file is a symlink to a directory.)

Comment: Show us the output of `ls -ld /media/path/to/log`.

Comment: @chepner The file was (with the others) downloaded to the computer by [arcget](http://www.nordugrid.org/documents/arc-ui.pdf) and than moved to its final destination by `mv`. Regarding your second comment: maybe you are right: `readlink -f log/` returns the absolute path to `log` (so, using the upper notation, this would be `/media/path/to/log`)

Comment: @JohnGordon ls: cannot access '/media/path/to/log': Not a directory

Comment: But that's the exact path you gave in your question.  Did you run that ls command in the same context (i.e within the VM) as the python code?

Comment: @JohnGordon a) Yes, I did. However, if I click on the `log` in the "File explorer" in Virtual Machine, the folder containing this file opens.  b) If this is really a symlink, why does `os.path.islink('/media/path/to/log')` returns False?

Comment: If `ls` says the path does not exist, something fishy is going on.  Try the command again without the `d` flag.  i.e. just use `ls -l`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Again, the same answer ls: cannot access '/media/path/to/log/': Not a directory

Comment: Please print these values: `oct(stat.S_IFDIR)` and `oct(os.lstat('/media/path/to/log').st_mode)`

Comment: @VPfB I do not know what is `oct` or how to "install" it (googling did not help, even after I excluded October, Calendar etc.). Currently, I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`stat.S_IFDIR'` as the response to `oct(stat.S_IFDIR)`

Comment: @Antoine `oct` is a Python (not bash) built-in (octal, i.e. base 8 representation of a number). No need to install anything. Start Python; `import os`, `import stat`, and then type the expressions from my comment. I'm sorry if something was not clear.

Comment: I don't understand why `ls` would say `Not a directory`.  Perhaps you meant `No such file or directory`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Nope. Every message I gave was copied (only the path was shortened)